# Visual Studio Release build deploys to Hololens, but Master build doesn't - Activation of Windows Store failed

Tags: visual-studio, build, hololens, windows-store, release-builds

I am using spectator view for recording and streaming our Hololens app([link](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityCompanionKit/tree/1.5.7.0/SpectatorView/Samples)) and Visual Studio 2017 to build our solution for the Hololens.

I have been using the following Visual Studio build configurations:

```
Master, x86.
```

However, with the same configurations, the project with Spectator View fails with an error:

```
The program '[5620] SpecTest.exe' has exited with code -1073740966 (0xc000035a).
Activation of the Windows Store app 'SpecTest_s9y1p3hwd5qda!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
```

We did notice that the app launched when we did a release build with the configuration:

```
Release, x86.
```

We require the Master build of the Hololens app because our project uses a Unity Timeline which for some reason doesn't work with the Release build. I searched the internet for this problem and tried almost every solution recommended there (Created a new license, deleted the bin folder and rebuilt the project, tried a Debug build). But, I believe it has something to do with the difference between the Release and Master build. We were previously able to do a master build without this Spectator View bit in our code.

Is there any way to do a Master build and overcome this error?